# how can i repair samsung galaxy s duos 2 GT-S7582 no sim card/no service

Tags: custom-roms

i already tried installing stock firmware the new and the old firmware philippine GLOBE but still nothing happen still no sim card/no service .. when i try to call it says "not registered to the network" please anyone help me .. even just advice what to do ..

Answer (score 1):

I also faced that problem. After changing the motherboard it rectified. Since it was done during warranty period, I did it free of cost. Many peoples suffer this problem and it is clear that it is manufacturing defect.